# Changing the "drop all"/"drop stack" keybind in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, keyboard

I'm experimenting to find the most comfortable keybinds for me and I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> would be perfect for dropping items. However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[drop item key]</kbd> drops the whole stack, which is also the case for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, meaning that I can't drop single items with this setup. Can I change the "drop all" keybind to something else? Anything goes, I'll even gladly install a mod if it allows that.

Answer (score 1):

I found [DropstackKeybind](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/dropstackkeybind), a mod that (hopefully) fits your needs. You have to use Forge for this to work and you said you didn't mind installing a mod so give it a try. I haven't tested the mod myself so I can't assure you that it will work. The other thing is that it says it only runs on 1.8.9 which is the version used mostly to play on servers like Hypixel. If you plan to use this on servers like Hypixel then it should supposedly fit your needs.

[DropstackKeybind page](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/dropstackkeybind)

Answer (score -1):

You can install a program onto your pc and switch Ctrl with whatever key( in this case p). Then switch your drop key to p. Now when you press Ctrl it will press p instead.

Comment: then you can't use you ctrl key in the normal spot, can't ctrl tab to other applications, etc